# How to download folders from Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-colaboratory

I know it's possible to download files from Google Colaboratory. At the moment I do this via files.download(). But is it possible to download a created directory in Colab?

I know how to code the unique ID and I will search for creating the masks. But in fact I have to download the directory directory_name with the same structure shown at the end (this saves time for me instead of running the code for it in Colab every time again after reconnecting to the VM).

So the question is: Is there any function to download the whole directory as a folder instead of downloading every image / mask for its own?

I want to make such a directory:

directory_name

... id_1

........ images

............... one image with id_1

........ masks

............... all the masks for the images (different ids)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `keras` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the folder directly from the files tab that you can find on an arrow on top left of the screen
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

Comment: this is true for files, but not for folders

Answer (score 15):

Too late to answer this, but here's what you can do to download a folder from colab to your local system: 
1. Create a zipped file in colab by:

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive('folder_name', 'zip', 'folder_name')
```

2. Download the zipped file: right click file > Download
Just unzip this when you want to use it later by:

```
! unzip -q zip_file_name.zip
```

Hope that answers your query!